# How does one find out if a Windows service is installed using (preferably) only batch?

Tags: windows, windows-services

I need to check if a Windows service is installed from a batch file. I can dip into something other than batch if I need to, but I would prefer not to. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
SC QUERY ftpsvc > NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1060 GOTO MISSING
ECHO EXISTS
GOTO END

:MISSING
ECHO SERVICE MISSING

:END
```

Note that the `SC QUERY` command queries by the short service name not the display name. You can find this name by looking at the General tab of a service's properties in Service Manager.

Answer (score 14):

You should using "query", not "Stop" or something else command, the "Stop" can stop your service if it's exist, then this is not the right way.

```
@echo OFF

set _ServiceName=SomeServiceName

sc query %_ServiceName% | find "does not exist" >nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 echo Service Does Not Exist.
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 echo Service Exist.
```

Comment: Does this only work on English language versions of windows?

Answer (score 4):

what about:

```
sc interrogate "nameofyourservicehere"
```

I've found this really useful since `tasklist` won't give informations on whether the service is installed or not. (or i did not find how)

Comment: Well this checks if the Service is running. However `sc GetDisplayName ServiceName` would work to check installed

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using `sc query` to verify if a windows service is installed and stop if found.

```
sc query | find /I "%tmpServiceName%" > nul
if not errorlevel 1 echo. && net stop %tmpServiceName%
if errorlevel 1 echo.   - Windows service %tmpServiceName% is not running or doesn't exist.
```

Answer (score -12):

you can run "net stop [servicename]" if it fails with "the service name is invalid" the service isn't installed

Comment: Wrong! Even short suspend of some services may be not wanted, what is more some services are protected and could not be stopped.

Comment: I also agree this shouldn't be marked as the answer although it could work in some cases.