# How to check in Windows if the service is not installed using batch file

Tags: service, batch-file

I'm trying to do a batch program that needs to check if the service is installed before checking if it is running/stopped.

I would just like to ask if there is any way that I can check the ERRORLEVEL of an uninstalled service when the OS is Windows XP.

In my code snippet:

```
ver | find /I "XP"
if %errorlevel%==0 goto ver_xp
goto ver_nonXP

:ver_xp
echo Windows XP
sc query myService > nul
echo %errorlevel%
if errorlevel ___I goto ServiceOk
if errorlevel ___ goto ServiceError
goto ServiceError

:ver_nonXP
echo Windows is not XP
sc query myService > nul
echo error1_percent %errorlevel%
if %errorlevel%==0 goto ServiceOk
if %errorlevel% NEQ '0' goto ServiceError
goto end

:ServiceError
echo Service is not installed
net helpmsg %errorlevel%
goto end

:ServiceError
rem do some operations here....
```

I tried to use

```
if errorlevel 1060 goto ServiceError
```

It seems that if the service is not installed, the condition above will always be false.

I made the errorlevel ____ because I don't know that the correct condition should be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sc query myService  |find "myService" >nul` will do the trick

Answer (score 2):

According to this answer this is possible in batch using method you described [How does one find out if a Windows service is installed using (preferably) only batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883099/how-does-one-find-out-if-a-windows-service-is-installed-using-preferably-only)

Alternatively you could query with powershell:

```
$serv_status = get-service "myService"
if($serv_status -ne $null) 
{ 
    // do some operations here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I prefer only batch file since this is the one that I'm told to use. I've seen that link already but I'm finding difficulties in catching the error itself for my "if" condition. And the error returned is "..service  is not installed.." not the same with the link provided. I don't know if piping for the specific string returned (using net) would be possible. I haven't found any commands for that yet.